# Tizen Shared Object Libraries won't be loaded on Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, shared-libraries, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk

I've been developing an app for the Samsung Gear S2 (which runs Tizen) for a while. I'm using Unity 5.3.5p3, and Tizen 2.4.0rev6 with Tizen Wearable 2.3.1 profile.

And now that I've almost finished, strange bugs appear.

I've made a Shared Object (.so) library, successfully connected it to Unity, successfully installed my app on the device, and everything works.

Everything works until I switch off "Development Build" in Unity build settings. Then, it seems like it can load the library (it gives me no error about missing functions or whatever), but the functions inside my library don't get executed at all, not even half a log.

What's going on here?

(I can publish some code if you want to, but I don't think it would be of any help, since it all works out fine on development build)

Comment: You may check the release build path and if that not works, then you may try to re-install the plugin.
As Tizen is not supporting all features of Unity, you may find those features in this link: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/tizen-unsupported.html
I would also suggest you to go through the "Tizen Player Settings" and "Publising Build" from the below link: 
http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PlayerSettingsTizen.html
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/916352/how-to-remove-development-build-stamp.html